# Set JPA Annotations at the member variable or at get methods of an entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i haven´t some big experiences with the topic JPA and Hibernate. For me it is not clear, when it is necessary to write the JPA annotation at the member variable of my entity class ans when i can use the get methods for my annotations. Is it right, that annotations should not being set at the set method of an entity?. Here is a small example:

```
public class MessageEntity implements Persistable{

    @ManyToOne
    StatusEntity state;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean freitext = false;

    private Collection<Variables> variables;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, targetEntity = Variables.class)
    public Collection<Variables> getVariables() {
       return this.variables;
    }
}
```

Also it is not clear for me, when i must use the attribute targetEntity. Can somebody explain that for me?

Maik

Answer (score 0):

The annotations can go either on the `properties or the getters`, but not on the setters.

In a one to many relationship, if the Set(collection) is specified without the generics, the targetEntity is required. If the Set<Generic> is used then the targetEntity is not required.

Ref: [Java api](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used any JPA annotations on getter methods, I'd assume its the same as annotating the variable at the top. I'd keep all annotations on the variables at the top, just to be cleaner.

For that "targetEntity" attribute on your @OneToMany I have not used, however I do use mappedBy when using @OneToMany. I think targetEntity is not needed in your case.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message_entity")
public class MessageEntity implements Persistable{

@ManyToOne
StatusEntity state;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Boolean freitext = false;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="message_entity"), cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIS
private Collection<Variables> variables;

public Collection<Variables> getVariables() {
       return this.variables;
    }
}
```